# I am getting error 404 in laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, web

[image]

I am registering a user for newsletter in website
so in web.php

```
// FrontEnd 
Route::post('store/newsletter','FrontController@StoreNewsletter')->name('store.newsletter');
```

in index.blade.php ,The form is in footer of index page
and index pages called by get

```
Route::get('/', function () {return view('pages.index');});



<form action="{{ route('store.newsletter') }} " method="post" class="newsletter_form">
    @csrf
     <input type="email" class="newsletter_input" required="required"
       placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email">
     <button class="newsletter_button" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

I even tried changing button to input in form

this is FrontController.php which is in app/Http/Controller/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class FrontController extends Controller
{

    public function StoreNewsletter(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request->all());

        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|unique:newsletters|max:55',
        ]);

        $data = [];
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        DB::table('newsletters')->insert($data);

        $notification = [
            'messege'    => 'Thanks For Subscribing',
            'alert-type' => 'success',
        ];

        return Redirect()->back()->with($notification);

    }
}
```

This __construct i have put after error for debug purposes

This is my table name

```
Schema::create('newsletters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

after putting `dd()` in `exceptions/handler.php`:
[image]

web.php content

```
//Newsletter
Route::get('admin/newsletter','Admin\Category\CouponController@Newsletter')- 
>name('admin.newsletter');  

// FrontEnd 
 Route::post('store/newsletter','FrontController@StoreNewsletter')- 
>name('store.newsletter');
```

JorgeMudry  11:26 PM
@aakash sharma I've use your code from stackoverflow and it is working for me. your problem is elsewhere

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212676/discussion-on-question-by-aakash-sharma-i-am-getting-error-404-in-laravel-websit).

Comment: The problem is solved , actually it is some browser problem or don't know what but, when folder name is Excise_File , Browser will run it even on excise_File so this was creating issue, so check the names of folder and browser url carefully

Answer (score -1):

You might need to add a GET method

**in the web.php file**

```
Route::get('store/newsletter','FrontController@viewNewsletter')->name('view.newsletter);
```

**In FrontController**

```
public function viewNewsletter()
{
return view('path to your view file');
}
```